# OBJ model loaded in LWJGL has a black area with no texture

Tags: java, opengl, model, textures, lwjgl

I have a problem with loading an .obj file in LWJGL and its textures.
The object is a tree(it's a paid model from TurboSquid, so I can't post it here,but here's the link if you want to see how it should look like):
http://www.turbosquid.com/FullPreview/Index.cfm/ID/701294

I wrote a custom OBJ loader using the LWJGL tutorial from their wiki. It looks like this:

```
public class OBJLoader {
public static Model loadModel(File f) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));

    Model m = new Model();
    String line;
    Texture currentTexture = null;
    while((line=reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        if(line.startsWith("v "))
        {
            float x = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1]);
            float y = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2]);
            float z = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[3]);
            m.verticies.add(new Vector3f(x,y,z));
        }else if(line.startsWith("vn "))
        {
            float x = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1]);
            float y = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2]);
            float z = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[3]);
            m.normals.add(new Vector3f(x,y,z));
        }else if(line.startsWith("vt "))
        {
            float x = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1]);
            float y = Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2]);
            m.texVerticies.add(new Vector2f(x,y));
        }else if(line.startsWith("f "))
        {
            Vector3f vertexIndicies = new Vector3f(Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1].split("/")[0]), 
                    Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2].split("/")[0]), 
                    Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[3].split("/")[0]));
            Vector3f textureIndicies = new Vector3f(Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1].split("/")[1]), 
                    Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2].split("/")[1]), 
                    Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[3].split("/")[1]));
            Vector3f normalIndicies = new Vector3f(Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[1].split("/")[2]), 
                    Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[2].split("/")[2]), 
                    Float.valueOf(line.split(" ")[3].split("/")[2]));

            m.faces.add(new Face(vertexIndicies,textureIndicies,normalIndicies,currentTexture.getTextureID()));
        }else if(line.startsWith("g "))
        {
            if(line.length()>2)
            {
                String name = line.split(" ")[1];
                currentTexture = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("res/" + name + ".png"));
                System.out.println(currentTexture.getTextureID());
            }
        }
    }


    reader.close();

    System.out.println(m.verticies.size() + " verticies");
    System.out.println(m.normals.size() + " normals");
    System.out.println(m.texVerticies.size() + " texture coordinates");
    System.out.println(m.faces.size() + " faces");
    return m;
}
}
```

Then I create a display list for my model using this code:

```
objectDisplayList = GL11.glGenLists(1);
    GL11.glNewList(objectDisplayList, GL11.GL_COMPILE);
    Model m = null;
    try {
        m = OBJLoader.loadModel(new File("res/untitled4.obj"));
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } 

    int currentTexture=0;
    for(Face face: m.faces)
    {
        if(face.texture!=currentTexture)
        {
            currentTexture = face.texture;
            GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, currentTexture);
        }


        GL11.glColor3f(1f, 1f, 1f);
        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES);

        Vector3f n1 = m.normals.get((int) face.normal.x - 1);
        GL11.glNormal3f(n1.x, n1.y, n1.z);
        Vector2f t1 = m.texVerticies.get((int) face.textures.x -1);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(t1.x, t1.y);
        Vector3f v1 = m.verticies.get((int) face.vertex.x - 1);
        GL11.glVertex3f(v1.x, v1.y, v1.z);



        Vector3f n2 = m.normals.get((int) face.normal.y - 1);
        GL11.glNormal3f(n2.x, n2.y, n2.z);
        Vector2f t2 = m.texVerticies.get((int) face.textures.y -1);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(t2.x, t2.y);
        Vector3f v2 = m.verticies.get((int) face.vertex.y - 1);
        GL11.glVertex3f(v2.x, v2.y, v2.z);


        Vector3f n3 = m.normals.get((int) face.normal.z - 1);
        GL11.glNormal3f(n3.x, n3.y, n3.z);
        Vector2f t3 = m.texVerticies.get((int) face.textures.z -1);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(t3.x, t3.y);
        Vector3f v3 = m.verticies.get((int) face.vertex.z - 1);
        GL11.glVertex3f(v3.x, v3.y, v3.z);

        GL11.glEnd();
    }
    GL11.glEndList();
```

The currentTexture is an int - it contains the ID of the currently used texture.

So my model looks absolutely fine without textures:
[image: 1]

But look what happens if I enable GL_TEXTURE_2D:
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]

As you can see an entire side of the tree appears to be missing - and it's not transparent, since it's not in the colour of the background - it's rendered black.

It's not a problem with the model - if I load it using Kanji's OBJ loader it works fine(but the thing is,that I need to write my own OBJ loader)
[image: 5]

this is my OpenGL init section:

```
//init display
    try {
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(Support.SCREEN_WIDTH, Support.SCREEN_HEIGHT));
        Display.create();
        Display.setVSyncEnabled(true);
    } catch (LWJGLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D);               
    GL11.glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);          

    GL11.glShadeModel(GL11.GL_SMOOTH);
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    GL11.glDepthFunc(GL11.GL_LESS);
    GL11.glDepthMask(true);
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_NORMALIZE); 



    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);

    GLU.gluPerspective (90.0f,800f/600f, 1f, 500.0f);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);

    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_CULL_FACE);
    GL11.glCullFace(GL11.GL_BACK);

    //enable lighting
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_LIGHTING);

    ByteBuffer temp = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(16);
    temp.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

    GL11.glMaterial(GL11.GL_FRONT, GL11.GL_DIFFUSE, (FloatBuffer)temp.asFloatBuffer().put(lightDiffuse).flip());
    GL11.glMaterialf(GL11.GL_FRONT, GL11.GL_SHININESS,(int)material_shinyness);

    GL11.glLight(GL11.GL_LIGHT2, GL11.GL_DIFFUSE, (FloatBuffer)temp.asFloatBuffer().put(lightDiffuse2).flip());              // Setup The Diffuse Light
    GL11.glLight(GL11.GL_LIGHT2, GL11.GL_POSITION,(FloatBuffer)temp.asFloatBuffer().put(lightPosition2).flip()); 
    GL11.glLight(GL11.GL_LIGHT2, GL11.GL_AMBIENT,(FloatBuffer)temp.asFloatBuffer().put(lightAmbient).flip()); 
    GL11.glLight(GL11.GL_LIGHT2, GL11.GL_SPECULAR,(FloatBuffer)temp.asFloatBuffer().put(lightDiffuse2).flip()); 

    GL11.glLightf(GL11.GL_LIGHT2, GL11.GL_CONSTANT_ATTENUATION, 0.1f);
    GL11.glLightf(GL11.GL_LIGHT2, GL11.GL_LINEAR_ATTENUATION, 0.0f);
    GL11.glLightf(GL11.GL_LIGHT2, GL11.GL_QUADRATIC_ATTENUATION, 0.0f);
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_LIGHT2);
```

I also have a different model of the same tree - way more detailed, exported straight from blender - does the same thing.

Comment: Compare UVs you get in your parser with UVs in the Obj file.May be your parser corrupts those.

Comment: Ok I managed to improve it....turns out the V parameter for the texture should be substracted from 1 before being applied to the model. So the code in the OBJ loader is:

            m.texVerticies.add(new Vector2f(x,1-y));

That makes the top of the tree appear correctly - however, the side is still black and now the underside of the tree is black as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering here, because i can't comment.

I did not read the code, what you are describing sounds like you didn't mind the orientation (i.e. the order in which the vertices are indexed) of the face. If the orientation is wrong, the texture coordinates have to be flipped as well.

Answer (score 0):

When you read the objet and create a displaylist write out a point is it has no texturecoordinate mathing to it. Ther can be a problem that not every vertex have texturecoordinates. Or check is the texure's size is 2^x sized in both direction? That would be help.